# link_to param scoping in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page which has a couple option links that set GET-based parameters to the page.

These links are created with the Rails HtmlHelper:

```
link_to section, {:company_id => params[:company_id], :view => section}
```

Notice how I have to retype out parameters just in case they've been selected before.

I want to know if I can achieve this same effect, to automatically account for all parameters so it's just easier to write and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
link_to section, params.merge({ :view => section })
```